# How to avoid null pointer error

Tags: java, null, pointers, arraylist

I trying to find whether the elements of 2 arrayLists are match or not.
But this code give me error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` since some of the elements are null.

How can I solved this problem?

```
String level []={"High","High","High","High","High","High"};
ArrayList<Object> n = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(level));

String choice []={null,"High","Low","High",null,"Medium"}; 
ArrayList<Object> m = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(choice));

//Check if the two arrayList are identical
for(int i=0; i<m.size(); i++){
   if(!(m.get(i).equals(n.get(i)))){   
 result= true;
 break;
   } 
} 
    return  result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `equals` method on some elements without first checking for `null`.

Change to:

```
for(int i=0; i<m.size(); i++){
   if(m.get(i) != null && !(m.get(i).equals(n.get(i)))){   
     result = true;
     break;
   } 
}
```

Or if you want to allow two `null` values to compare equal:

```
for(int i=0; i<m.size(); i++){
   if (m.get(i) == null) {
     if (n.get(i) != null) {
       result = true;
     }
   } else if(!(m.get(i).equals(n.get(i)))){   
     result = true;
   } 
   if (result) {
     break;
   }
}
```

One thing I don't get - why are you setting result to true when you find a mismatch?  Don't you want to return true if both lists match and false otherwise?

Comment: Should check if m and n are both null and set result to true if so.

Comment: Yep, was adding that when I realized he might want to allow it.  Thanks though.

Comment: Might want to cache that first `m.get(i)`, the JIT may not realize it can rely on it not having changed between the two retrievals. (And in fact, without knowing the OP's code better, we don't know that either! :-) )

Comment: @T.J. Crowder:  I thought of that while I was typing but didn't think it would add much in the context of the question.  Still, a valid point.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I want to allow null. Thank you, Thank you,Thank you :-)

Comment: There's a typo with result == true;

Comment: @Jessy if you want to "allow nulls" use `enum`.  You never nulls to represent a valid value

Answer (score 8):

Just use Arrays.equals, like so:

```
    String level []={"High","High","High","High","High","High"};

    String choice []={null,"High","Low","High",null,"Medium"}; 

    return Arrays.equals(level, choice);
```

Comment: While this can be a solution, I would discourage the use of Arrays to a newbie.  Everybody should use List whenever possible

Comment: @Pyrolistical - I agree Lists should be used whenever possible. But since the OP had the 'lists' in arrays originally it seemed like a waste to convert when a standard util function did what is needed.

Comment: You solved his immediate problem, but I say you have to go a step further and try to understand what the root of the problem is.  The real problem here is he is using arrays instead of List.  We should try to teach them more than just solving their problem

Answer (score 2):

The root of this problem could be you are using null as an actual value.

Just looking at your code you could use `enum` and instead of null use an EMPTY value.  Then you can actually compare with in a list without nullpointerexceptions.

Check this out:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Also try to avoid using arrays.  Just use List but use the proper type.  Don't use `List<Object>` that is almost never valid.

null should indicate an error or testing only.  It should never be used in valid code as you will create null pointer exception bugs during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the first list never contains nulls switch the call around

```
if(!(n.get(i).equals(m.get(i)))){
```

also specifying `ArrayList<Object>` is bad practice, use `List<String>` if it is actually `String` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the objects are the same object (or both null) first. Check for null before you do the equals() test.

```
    boolean result = true;
    String level[] = { "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High" };
    ArrayList<String> n = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(level));

    String choice[] = { null, "High", "Low", "High", null, "Medium" };
    ArrayList<String> m = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(choice));

    // Check if the two arrayList are identical
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
      String mElement = m.get(i);
      String nElement = n.get(i);

      if (mElement == nElement) {
        result = true;
      } else if ((mElement == null) || (nElement == null)) {
        result = false;
        break;
      } else if (!(m.get(i).equals(n.get(i)))) {
        result = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `if` like this in order to check for both double-nullity and single-nullity:

```
if((m.get(i) == null && n.get(i) == null) || (m.get(i) != null && !(m.get(i).equals(n.get(i)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than solving this specific problem, give yourself a tool you can use over and again, e.g.:

```
public static final boolean areEqual(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return o1 == null ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2);
}
```

...in some handy utility class, then use that in your loop.

But of course, for this *specific* requirement, [derivation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143845/derivation) has the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561951/how-to-avoid-null-pointer-error/2562001#2562001) (use `java.util.Arrays.equals(Object[],Object[])`).

Answer (score 0):

## Remove NULLs

You can remove NULL values from your [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) objects before processing.

```
myList.removeAll( Collections.singleton( null ) );
```

The [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class is a bunch of convenient utility methods. Not to be confused with [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (singular), the interface that parents [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and is implemented by [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

See this posting, [Removing all nulls from a List in Java](http://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-nulls-from-list), for more discussion.